# Why can't mongo push my ObjectId in a predefined array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb4.0

I have made my model, it has this Schema:

```
const CompanySchema = new Schema({
    companyName: {
      type: String,
      required: [true,'the name of the companies working on the game are missing.']
    },
    companyAge: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true,'the age of the company is missing.']
    },
    companyDeveloper:[{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "developer"
    }]
  });
```

I am trying to push a element into the companyDeveloper array like this:

```
  addDev(req,res,next){
    const companyId = req.params.id;
    const companyDeveloper = ObjectId.fromString(req.body.companyDeveloper);
    Company.findById({_id: companyId})
    .then((company) => company.companyDeveloper.push({companyDeveloper}))
    .then(company => res.send(company))
    .catch(next);
  }
```

but I keep getting this error:
"error": "ObjectId is not defined".

Before I tried casting it, I got this error
Cast to ObjectId failed for value

How can I get this function to work?

**printscreen**

[postman call error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A0T8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ObjectId class from mongoose is defined on `Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`

You can require it in the file where you define `addDev`

```
const ObjectId = require('mongoose').Schema.Types.ObjectId
```

or load mongoose into a global where you initialize your node code so you can access it in any file:

```
global.Mongoose = require('mongoose')
```

And then use it in your method:

```
const companyDeveloper = Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId.fromString(req.body.companyDeveloper);
```